# Unable to find the cause of segmentation fault of huffman coding to do entropy encoding and decoding in c

Tags: c, encoding, decoding, huffman-code, entropy

I have been looking at the code to do entropy encoding and decoding with of huffman coding in c, and I cannot seem to find the reason why I keep getting segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int MAX_TREE_HT = 100;

struct MinHeapNode {
    char data;
    unsigned freq;
    struct MinHeapNode* left, * right;
};

struct MinHeap {
    unsigned size;
    unsigned capacity;
    struct MinHeapNode** array;
};

struct MinHeapNode* newNode(char data, unsigned freq) {
    struct MinHeapNode* temp = (struct MinHeapNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct MinHeapNode));
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->freq = freq;
    return temp;
}

struct MinHeap* createMinHeap(unsigned capacity) {
    struct MinHeap* minHeap = (struct MinHeap*)malloc(sizeof(struct MinHeap));
    minHeap->size = 0;
    minHeap->capacity = capacity;
    minHeap->array = (struct MinHeapNode**)malloc(minHeap->capacity * sizeof(struct MinHeapNode*));
    return minHeap;
}

void swapMinHeapNode(struct MinHeapNode** a, struct MinHeapNode** b) {
    struct MinHeapNode* t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

void minHeapify(struct MinHeap* minHeap, int idx) {
    int smallest = idx;
    int left = 2 * idx + 1;
    int right = 2 * idx + 2;

    if (left < minHeap->size && minHeap->array[left]->freq < minHeap->array[smallest]->freq)
        smallest = left;

    if (right < minHeap->size && minHeap->array[right]->freq < minHeap->array[smallest]->freq)
        smallest = right;

    if (smallest != idx) {
        swapMinHeapNode(&minHeap->array[smallest], &minHeap->array[idx]);
        minHeapify(minHeap, smallest);
    }
}

int isSizeOne(struct MinHeap* minHeap) {
    return (minHeap->size == 1);
}

struct MinHeapNode* extractMin(struct MinHeap* minHeap) {
    struct MinHeapNode* temp = minHeap->array[0];
    minHeap->array[0] = minHeap->array[minHeap->size - 1];
    --minHeap->size;
    minHeapify(minHeap, 0);
    return temp;
}

void insertMinHeap(struct MinHeap* minHeap, struct MinHeapNode* minHeapNode) {
    ++minHeap->size;
    int i = minHeap->size - 1;
    minHeap->array[i] = minHeapNode;
    while (i && minHeap->array[i]->freq < minHeap->array[(i - 1) / 2]->freq) {
        swapMinHeapNode(&minHeap->array[i], &minHeap->array[(i - 1) / 2]);
        i = (i - 1) / 2;
    }
}

void buildMinHeap(struct MinHeap* minHeap) {
    int n = minHeap->size - 1;
    int i;
    for (i = (n - 1) / 2; i >= 0; --i)
        minHeapify(minHeap, i);
}

void printArr(int arr[], int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int isLeaf(struct MinHeapNode* root) {
    return !(root->left) && !(root->right);
}

struct MinHeap* createAndBuildMinHeap(char data[], int freq[], int size) {
    struct MinHeap* minHeap = createMinHeap(size);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        minHeap->array[i] = newNode(data[i], freq[i]);
    minHeap->size = size;
    buildMinHeap(minHeap);
    return minHeap;
}

struct MinHeapNode* buildHuffmanTree(char data[], int freq[], int size) {
    struct MinHeapNode *left, *right, *top;
    struct MinHeap* minHeap = createAndBuildMinHeap(data, freq, size);
    while (!isSizeOne(minHeap)) {
        left = extractMin(minHeap);
        right = extractMin(minHeap);
        top = newNode('$', left->freq + right->freq);
        top->left = left;
        top->right = right;
        insertMinHeap(minHeap, top);
    }
    return extractMin(minHeap);
}

void printCodes(struct MinHeapNode* root, int arr[], int top) {
    if (root->left) {
        arr[top] = 0;
        printCodes(root->left, arr, top + 1);
    }
    if (root->right) {
        arr[top] = 1;
        printCodes(root->right, arr, top + 1);
    }
    if (isLeaf(root)) {
        printf("%c: ", root->data);
        printArr(arr, top);
    }
}

void HuffmanCodes(char data[], int freq[], int size) {
    struct MinHeapNode* root = buildHuffmanTree(data, freq, size);
    int arr[MAX_TREE_HT], top = 0;
    printCodes(root, arr, top);
}

void encode(char* str, char* encoded_str, struct MinHeapNode* root) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    if (isLeaf(root)) {
        while (*str != root->data)
            str++;
        while (*str == root->data) {
            *encoded_str = '1';
            encoded_str++;
            str++;
        }
        return encode(str, encoded_str, root);
    }
    if (*str == root->data) {
        *encoded_str = '0';
        encoded_str++;

        encode(str + 1, encoded_str, root->left);
    } else {
        encode(str, encoded_str, root->right);
    }
}

void decode(char* encoded_str, struct MinHeapNode* root, char* decoded_str) {
    struct MinHeapNode* curr = root;
    while (*encoded_str) {
        if (*encoded_str == '0')
            curr = curr->left;
        else
            curr = curr->right;
        if (isLeaf(curr)) {
            *decoded_str = curr->data;
            decoded_str++;
            curr = root;
        }
        encoded_str++;
    }
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "this is a test";
    int freq[256] = { 0 };
    int size = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        freq[str[i]]++;
        size++;
    }
    int unique = 0;
    char data[size];
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (freq[i]) {
            data[unique] = (char)i;
            unique++;
        }
    }
    HuffmanCodes(data, freq, unique);
    char encoded_str[100], decoded_str[100];
    struct MinHeapNode* root = buildHuffmanTree(data, freq, unique);
    encode(str, encoded_str, root);
    printf("Encoded string: %s\n", encoded_str);
    decode(encoded_str, root, decoded_str);
    printf("Decoded string: %s\n", decoded_str);
    return 0;
}
```

With the several try and error with commenting out section by section, it was found that it's caused somewhere inside the encoding function. This is not the code I wrote myself and is written with some references online. And the output should be the following.

```
 : 00
a: 010
e: 011
h: 100
i: 1010
s: 1011
t: 110
Encoded string: 0101110101011101110111111001101
Decoded string: this is a test
```

Instead I get the following.

```
a: 0
e: 10
h: 110
i: 1110
s: 11110
 : 111110
t: 111111
zsh: segmentation fault
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `freq[str[i]]++` ---> doesn't make much sense to me. ```str[i]``` will evaluate to a ```char```,  not an ```int```.

Comment: Crash happens at line 147 `while (*str != root->data)`, when changing it to `while (*str && *str != root->data)` you will get an endless loop somewhere. Think about what happens in this line when `root->data` is not in `str`. https://godbolt.org/z/M6f6KTqPK

Comment: When you add `-g -fsanitize=address` to the compiler flags for gcc or clang you will get very good hints where the problems occur.

Comment: `freq[str[i]]++;` This might cause trouble if you are not limiting your input to printable strings. As `str[i]` is a `char` it may be signed on your system resulting in a negative index.

Comment: OT: If this code is taken from some other site, you must provide a proper link to it.

Comment: How do you know what the output should be?

Comment: `return encode(str, encoded_str, root);` That function is a `void` function. What do you want to return here?

Comment: It helps a lot to run it in a debugger so you can see which line of code it faults on. Then you likely don't even need to ask about it on stackoverflow. You'll figure it out on your own.

Comment: Your "should be" output is wrong. The code is not complete, where the `111` prefix is missing, and the "encoded string" has no relation whatsoever to coding that text with that code. Where did you get that from?

Answer (score 1):

Forget the fault. Your codes are all wrong. Get that working first. (Comment out the stuff in `main()` after `HuffmanCodes()`.)

The problem is that all of your frequencies are zeros! Why? Because you are indexing two completely different things with the same index, expecting them to be related. `data[i]` is the `i`<sup>th</sup> unique character that appears in the string. `freq[i]` on the other hand is the frequency of the *character* `i`. You are then pulling the frequencies of the first seven byte values, 0..6, which are all zero.

Everything from there on falls apart. So fix that first.

You don't need `data[]` and `unique` anyway. Just call `buildHuffmanTree()` with `freq[]`. Step through all of `freq[]` once, and from that directly build the initial elements of the heap, each when `freq[i] != 0`. Then the character is `i` and the frequency is `freq[i]`.

Other comments:

1. You are not checking for `malloc()` failures.
2. There are no `free()`s!
3. You build the same Huffman tree twice. Why?
4. Why 100 for `MAX_TREE_HT`, and the sizes of the encoded and decoded strings? Figure out what those need to be.
5. As noted in the comments, your `freq[str[i]]++;` needs to be `freq[str[i] & 0xff]++;`. `char` is signed, so you will be trying to access negative index elements of `freq` for bytes greater than 127 without the `& 0xff`.
6. Your `encode()` function makes no sense at all. Delete it and start over. (Your `decode()` function looks fine.) Hint: traverse the Huffman tree to build a table of codes. Then use that to encode.
7. Your "should be" output is wrong. Ignore that, however it is you came up with it or found it.

Answer (score 0):

```
void encode(char* str, char* encoded_str, struct MinHeapNode* root) {
if (root == NULL)
    return;
if (isLeaf(root)) {
    while (*str != root->data)
    {
        printf("str[]=%c", *str); // Here you can see that you have an overflow *******
        str++;
    }
    while (*str == root->data) {
        *encoded_str = '1';
        encoded_str++;
        str++;
    }
    return encode(str, encoded_str, root);
}
if (*str == root->data) {
    *encoded_str = '0';
    encoded_str++;

    encode(str + 1, encoded_str, root->left);
} else {
    encode(str, encoded_str, root->right);
}
```

}

Just add a condition in your while loop to make sure you don't overflow your string:

```
while (*str  && *str != root->data) // HERE and in all other loops
{
    str++;
}
```

BUT ! first you need to fix the fact that :
char encoded_str[100], decoded_str[100]; are empty and not null terminated so you can go through them in a loop :

```
encoded_str[end_index] = '\0';
while (*str ....) // it will stop at the '/0' in case you dont find *str == root->data.
```

the problem in your encode function is that you never go out of the recursion. hope this will help you :).